# Springboot test Mockmvc nested exception in HttpServlet response

Tags: spring-boot, testing, mockmvc

I am trying to do a testing which is for checking springboot security.I actually not very familar with using mockmvc test.And i have got an error here:

```
2023-01-16 10:01:13.650 ERROR 17724 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mockMvc' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc]: Factory method 'mockMvc' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
```

My test code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(AuthController.class)
class StoreserviceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private JpaUserservice jpaUserservice;

    @MockBean
    private JpaUserrepository jpaUserrepository;

    @MockBean
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;





    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;


    public void setup(){
        mvc=MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();
    }




    @WithMockUser("/Alex-1")
    @Test
    void checksecurity() throws Exception {

        MvcResult result =mvc.perform(get("/jpauser/alex")
                )
                .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError()).andReturn();
        assertEquals(401,result.getResponse().getStatus());
    }
}
```

Do anyone know the reason for getting this error?

Comment: did you get the answer? May be you have javax.* libraries and you need to move to jakarta.* but somewhere in project referring to  javax.*